# How to get Apache "Redirect" to stop appending full URL path to redirect target

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

If I edit the `.htaccess` file for a site, say oldsite.com, and put this:

```
Redirect permanent / http://newsite.com/page
```

It works fine if I surf to oldsite.com. But if I surf to oldsite.com/about, it goes to http://newsite.com/pageabout

How do I just take any hit to the old site and put it to an absolute URL without carrying over the rest of the path?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^ http://newsite.com/page
```

Should do it.

Comment: Also, if you want a 302 just omit `permanent` e.g.: `RedirectMatch ^ http://newsite.com/page`

Comment: Is there anyway to redirect to `/page` excluding the full hostname? Apache is always adding `http://newsite.com/page` when we specify only `/page` which is a problem.